# Is there an embedded opposite of strings.Repeat("0", 3) (detecting number of lead zeros) in Golang?

Tags: go

I have strings starting with 0's. need to get number of leading zeros:
Something like:

```
func LeadZeros(num string) int{
    // count the leading zeros
    return leadZerosNumber
}

LeadZeros("0012") --> 2
LeadZeros("5")    --> 0
LeadZeros("05")   --> 1
LeadZeros("0")    --> 0 (1 also good)
LeadZeros("00")   --> 1 (2 also good)
```

Looking for something embedded in go (or very short format)

e.g for writing there is: strings.Repeat("0", 3)

Comment: Any gotchas? I can't see any reason why this can't be done by simply counting from the left.

Comment: Looking for something embedded in GO, or very short format.
example for writing:   strings.Repeat(padStr, pLen) .   Need the read function

Comment: Maybe you just need https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Atoi

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: Homework

Comment: @SharonKatz what do you mean by "embedded"? As Volker is pointing out, this seems like a homework question without enough context or constraints.

Comment: I meant to ask if anything is embedded in the language.
e.g for writing there is:

strings.Repeat("0", 3)

 but agree to close or delete this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func LeadZeros(num string) int {

    i := 0
    for ;i < len(num) && num[i] == '0'; i++ {
    }

    return i
}
```

There are a lot of ways to do this and I would suggest the easiest to understand. Here is another one-liner:

```
func LeadZeros(num string) int {
    return len(num) - len(strings.TrimLeft(num, "0"))
}
```

Comment: One might also want to range over the string runes rather than bytes so you don't match `0x30` in multi-byte characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
func LeadZeros(num string) int{
    leadZerosNumber := 0
    for leadZerosNumber < len(num) && num[leadZerosNumber] == '0' {  
        leadZerosNumber++
    }

    return leadZerosNumber
}
```

You can check all entire code on [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/49c9XQfC3Ho)

To adapt code to output these cases:

> LeadZeros("0")    --> 0
>
> LeadZeros("00")   --> 1

Just change **for** condition from `leadZerosNumber < len(num) && num[leadZerosNumber] == '0'` to `leadZerosNumber < len(num) - 1 && num[leadZerosNumber] == '0'`

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main(){
   fmt.Println(LeadingZeros("0010"))
}


func LeadingZeros(s string) int {
c:=0
 for _,v := range s {
    if v=='0'{
        c++
    }else{
        break
    }
 }
 return c
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using regular expressions:

```
func LeadingZeros(str string) int {
    re := regexp.MustCompile("^0.*")
    match := re.FindString(str)
    return len(match)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    yourString := "0012"
    fmt.Println("Number Of Initial 0 = ", leadZeros(yourString))
}

func leadZeros(num string) (leadZerosNumber int) {

    for index := range num {
        if string(num[index]) == "0" {
            leadZerosNumber++
        } else {
            break
        }
    }

    return leadZerosNumber
}
```